# Domain and range of function-inverse composition (set theory)

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory

Given $f:A \to B$ (no assumptions on whether the function is injective/surjective). Let $X \subset A$, and $Y \subset B$.

> Prove: (i) $X \subset f^{-1}(f(X))$ (ii) $Y \supset f(f^{-1}(Y))$

How to prove this using only basic set theory?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(i)$ If $x\in X$, then $f(x)\in f(X)$ and so $x\in f^{-1}(f(X))$. Hence $$X\subseteq f^{-1}(f(X))$$.

$(ii)$ If $y\in f(f^{-1}(Y))$, there exists $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$ such that $f(x)=y$. Since $x\in f^{-1}(Y)$, then $y=f(x)\in Y$. Therefore $$f(f^{-1}(Y))\subseteq Y.$$

Answer (score 0):

(i) $f^{-1}(S)$ is defined as $ \{ a $ $\in$ $ A: f(a) $ $\in$ $ S \}$. 
Therefore, $ f^{-1}(f(X)) = \{ x $ $\in$ $ : f(x) $ $\in$ $ f(X) \}$. But for every $x$ $\in$ $X$ we have $f(x)$ $\in$ $f(X)$, so we conclude  $X \subset f^{-1}(f(X))$.

(ii) $f(S)$ is defined as $\{ b $ $\in$  $ B: \exists s$ $\in$ $ S $, $ f(s) = b\}$. So $f(f^{-1}(Y)) = \{ b $ $\in$ $ B:\exists x$ $\in$ $ f^{-1}(Y) $, $ f(x) = b\}$. But $x $ $\in$ $ f^{-1}(Y)$ implies $f(x) $ $\in$ $ Y$ (why?). So $f(f^{-1}(Y)) \subset Y$.